# Difference between following examples (random number)

Tags: javascript

I can't realize the difference between the following two examples:

```
var numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

Example 1:

```
console.log(numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length - 1) + 1])
```

Example 2:

```
console.log(numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)])
```

Comment: The first example will never select `"one"`. *edit* oh wait, it will

Comment: I'm getting it by running it :)

Check it for your self.

Comment: `var numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
console.log(numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length - 1) + 1])
console.log(numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)])
Output: one
Output: one`

Comment: Right. What is the actual point of the question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what is the difference and why is this working...  I should get numbers[-1] at some point, but I don't... right?

Comment: The `console.log(Math.floor(-0.3272145118907286))` will give you `-1`. But then it will give you the 0, as -1 + 1 = 0. So why to use it in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick breakdown, and how you should reason when trying to understand problems like this:

```
Math.random() -> outputs number in the [0, 1) range (0 <= x < 1)
names.length = 3
Math.floor() -> rounds down or removes any trailing decimals (0.9 -> 0, 1.245 -> 1)
```

Substituting the above in your code, your first example `numbers` index becomes:

```
console.log(numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length - 1) + 1])

-> Math.floor((0 <= x < 1) * 3 - 1) + 1
-> Math.floor((0 <= x < 3) - 1) + 1
-> Math.floor(-1 <= x < 2) + 1
-> { -1, 0, 1 } + 1

Possible indices are of the set { 0, 1, 2 }
```

Second example:

```
console.log(numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)])

-> Math.floor((0 <= x < 1) * 3)
-> Math.floor(0 <= x < 3)

Possible indices are of the set { 0, 1, 2 }
```

**Both outputs are identical.**

Both algorithms result in the same possible indices, both valid for choosing a random array value. Obviously the simpler solution is better.

Use a similar process for any questions like this in the future.

Comment: `Math.random` range is `0 ≤ x < 1`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Fixed

Comment: @kugi Happy to help. Welcome to SO!